# Arabic bibliography with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, fontspec, arabic

I haven't found any mention of the possibility of inserting a bibliography entry with `biblatex` in Arabic script (Arabic in this case).

Is there any way I can do it?

Comment: Me too I couldn't make an arabic bibliography in a completely arabic text (or with a latin-language) using polyglossia and biblatex because there's no arabic localization in biblatex. I've asked the package maintainers about such a localization but it does not seem to be easy to do : http://sourceforge.net/p/biblatex/features/101/

Answer (score 3):

I was not entirely sure what your question was. Do you want a pdf, entirely in Arabic, or a pdf in, e.g., English with the option to reference Arabic literature *without* transliterating the bibliographical information?

Anyway: here comes an example showing that it *is* possible to typeset an Arabic reference using `biblatex`and `biber`.

This answer is far from being perfect. Many thing would need to be tweaked or it to be perfect, e.g.:

1. the commas used are the wrong commas fro Arabic text
2. generally, the syntax would need ot be adjusted
3. maybe you'd like the Arabic footnotes to be right-aligned (this is possible, but I don't know how
4. an arabic number for the `footnotemark` would be nice (easy to achieve!)
5. you'd need arabic expressions for "edited by" etc.
6. ...

But all that should be possible.

Follow up question: is it possible to have *only* the Arabic footnotes right-aligned and keep the english footnotes left-aligned?

### working example:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatexmk
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, DIV=calc]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}
    \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.3]{Arabic Typesetting}

\usepackage[style=verbose,backend=biber]{biblatex}
    \DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}% postnotes without p. and pp.

\newcommand{\arabtext}[1]   % Arabic inside LTR
    {\bgroup\luatextextdir TRT\arabicfont #1\egroup}
\newcommand{\arabnr}[1]     % for digits inside Arabic text
    {\bgroup\luatextextdir TLT #1\egroup}
\newcommand{\afootnote}[1]  % Arabic footnotes
    {\footnote{\arabtext{#1}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{ibnsina:shifa:physics:ar,
    author = {\arabtext{ابن سينا}},
    year = {\arabnr{١٤١٧}},
    title = {\arabtext{السماع الطبيعى من كتاب الشفاء}},
    publisher = {\arabtext{دار المناهل}},
    location = {\arabtext{بيروت}},
        }
    @book{ibnsina:shifa:physics:en,
    author = {Avicenna},
    year = {1996},
    title = {Al-Samāʿ al-ṭabīʿī min Kitāb al-Šifāʾ},
    publisher = {Dār al-Manāhil},
    location = {Beirut}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\noindent Text with an English reference in the footnote.\footnote{\cite[12]{ibnsina:shifa:physics:en}.}

\noindent Text with an Arabic reference in the footnote.\afootnote{\cite[\arabnr{١٢}]{ibnsina:shifa:physics:ar}.}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wanted -- to insert bibliographies in Arabic without transliterating them. I didn't know it was as easy as using \arabtext{} in the bibliography! Does it work just like \textarabic{} in polyglossia? Still not sure how it will look in the text, though. By the way, can I compile with xelatex (I see you used lualatex)?

Comment: can you pls care to answer Joseph whether xelatex can be used instead of lualatex? How to show المراجع instead of the usual `Bibliography`?

Comment: @Joseph : I am sorry but I don't know anything about `xelatex`. I guess that it works with `xelatex`, too -- somehow similarly.

Comment: @doctorate : The title of the bibliography can be customised by `\renewcommand{\bibname}{whatever you like}`

Comment: @ClintEastwood, it didn't work, the only worked for me is posted as update2 here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172541/how-to-do-a-proper-bibliography-in-arabic-language-with-xelatex-and-biblatex-bib?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

The way I solve this exact problem, and which works with `polyglossia` and `biblatex` under XeLaTeX, is to use `\textarabic`. I'm convinced this is the best solution possible at the moment. If it doesn't work for you, please let me know why and I'll try to adapt my answer.

Since you complained about me having used the example from another answer, here's an example of my own, put into a MWS to show how to make use of it:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Arabic Typesetting}
% redefine \textarabic{} to never be italic
\let\oldtextarabic\textarabic
\renewcommand{\textarabic}{\upshape\oldtextarabic}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=mla]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{example.bib}
@book{Jamii2005,
  location = {\textarabic{بيروت}},
  title = {\textarabic{قاموس الفصاحة العمانية - ما حفظته الدارجة العمانية لللغة العربية}},
  volumes = {2},
  publisher = {\textarabic{‏‏دار أحياء التراث العربي}},
  author = {\textarabic{الجامعي}, \textarabic{أبو قاسم محمود بن حميد}},
  date = {2005},
  langid = {arabic}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{example.bib}

\begin{document}
  \section{Example}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \parencite[p. 123]{Jamii2005} consectetur.
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Compiled document]

@Werner: thank you for the formatting help!

Comment: I deleted my earlier comment. This is not a viable answer. In addition to being incomplete (my earlier complaint), you have simply copied part(!!) of an existing answer. Without adding something to distinguish this from @ClintEastwood's answer, I think that this answer should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by using `Persian-bib`, please go to CTAN and download `Persian-bib`, put it in your working directory then follow these few steps:

- copy and past these code lines into your preamble:

  ```
  \usepackage{xepersian}
  \settextfont[Scale=1]{XB Zar}%{XB Niloofar}
  \setlatintextfont[Scale=1]{Linux Libertine}
  \defpersianfont\Sayeh[Scale=1]{XB Kayhan Sayeh}
  ```
- go to the appropriate part of your document and insert this:

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{asa-fa}%{chicago-fa}%{plainnat-fa}%
  \bibliography{MyReferences}
  ```

`{asa-fa}`= the adapted file for RTL languages, `{MyReferences}`= is your `.bib` file

*please do not forget to add necessary fonts

Comment: This answer does not use `biblatex`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this solution woorks with natbib package