# Sorting bibliography cannot be turned off in Biblatex when writing in Arabic

Tags: biblatex, sorting, polyglossia, arabic, right-to-left

I want the citations to appear in the bibliography in the order of their appearance in the text and *not* according to their alphabet. I know there is an argument for that which is `sorting=none`. However, that didn't work when I was writing a document mainly in Arabic as in the MWE below, which is related to this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172541/how-to-do-a-proper-bibliography-in-arabic-language-with-xelatex-and-biblatex-bib).

**MWE Code**

```
\documentclass[oneside,16pt]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Mapping=arabicdigits]{USAMA NASKH}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic,Mapping=arabicdigits]{USAMA NASKH}
\newfontfamily\arabicfonttt[Script=Arabic,Mapping=arabicdigits]{USAMA NASKH}
%\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[style=numeric,sorting=none,backend=biber]{biblatex} % both citations and bibliography list won't show up in the pdf

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  references = {المراجع},
}
\makeatletter
\def\abx@comma{\ifdim\lastkern>\z@\unkern\fi\abx@puncthook{،}}% \makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@book{ref1,
    author = {{ابن سينا}},
    year = {1417},
    title = {السماع الطبيعى من كتاب الشفاء},
    publisher = {دار المناهل},
    location = {بيروت},
}
@book{ref2,
    author = {الجواهري},
    year = {1418},
    title = {اسم مستعار للكتاب},
    publisher = {دار المناهل},
    location = {بيروت},
}

@book{ref3,
    author = {يزيد بن معاوية},
    year = {1419},
    title = {اسم غير حقيقي للكتاب},
    publisher = {دار المناهل},
    location = {بيروت},
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}


\begin{document}

هنا كتابة ألنص باللغة العربية، نلاحظ عند إدخال احد المراجع \parencite{ref3} يظهر في باب المراجع بشكل طبيعي، لكن عند إضافة مرجع آخر مثلا \parencite{ref1} فإننا نلاحظ عدم ظهوره بالتسلسل الصحيح في باب المراجع حسب ظهوره. هذا مرجع ثالث للتأكد \parencite{ref2}.


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**MWE Output**
[image]

**Output post-update**
[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce using XeTeX and using `sorting=none`. What version of biber/biblatex are you using `biber --version` and add `\listfiles` to your preamble and the version of biblatex will be in the log file.

Comment: Biber v1.7 - biblatex 2013/07/15 v2.7a programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB).

Comment: The latest versions are Biber v1.8 and biblatex 2.8a. If you can update, this may solve your issue.

Comment: Problem was solved after updating both `biber` and `biblatex`, see update.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem solved by updating to the current versions of `biblatex` and Biber (see comments and updated question).